# Can we fetch data from firebase database of an other app?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android app and an IOS, both connected to the Firebase database. I want to fetch the data in the ios app from the database of the android app and vice verse. Is it possible ? if yes then how? and if not, Then what will be the solution ?

Comment: Would it not be easier to have both apps talk to the same database?

Answer (score 0):

You can register multiple apps in the project settings those apps can be on multiple platforms and they can communicate with your database.

So basically you need to go to `Firebase Console > Settings cog > Project settings > Add an app`. Adding app will allow you to share database (and other firebase features) securely across apps/platforms